# when on the parent page, how can I show the child pages using wp_nav_menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently doing this with `wp_list_child_pages` with the following code:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post;

    // Vars
    $page = get_the_title();
    $id = $post->ID;

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0&depth=1' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $id . '&echo=0&depth=1' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $html_out = '';

        $html_out .= '<div class="child-page-container child-page-' . $id . '">';
            // $html_out .= '<h2>' . $page . '</h2>';
            $html_out .= '<ul class="child-page-list">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
        $html_out .= '</div>'; // child-page-container
    }

    return $html_out;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

But this doesn't exactly do what I want. I need to show the structure I've set up in Appearance > Menus and it would only need to show the child pages of the parent page I'm on.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Check if any of those help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5797974/1427878, https://christianvarga.com/how-to-get-submenu-items-from-a-wordpress-menu-based-on-parent-or-sibling/, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120419

Comment: @CBroe these resources look promising, I'll give them a thorough read and test later on today, thanks.